# Please explain what does this friend declaration mean?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch &sw);
```

Comment: It overloads `operator <<` for the class `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch`.

Comment: What is mysterious or unclear in this declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it means it exists an operator << (certainly in global namespace or in a namespace of your current class) taking an ostream & as a first parameter and a const CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch & as a second parameter and this operator may access private members of your current class (which is certainly CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch)

Answer (score 0):

Literally?  It's a declaration for a freestanding `<<` operator that has an `ostream` on the left and a `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch` on the right.  The expression yields an `ostream` reference.

Semantically?  It's a stream insertion operator.  You know how you can say `std::cout << someString;`?  Well, that's because somewhere, there's a declaration that says `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const string &str);`.  The line you're asking about was almost certainly found in the `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch` class, and gives that operator the access it needs to output one of those objects.  So now you can say `std::cout << mySnmpMaintenanceSwitch;` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This line declares an `operator<<` which takes two parameters: a reference to an instance `std::ostream` and a constant reference to an instance of `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch`. It will allow you to write some information about an instance of `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch` to output stream like

```
operator<< ( std::cout , CSnmpMaintenanceSwitchInstance );
```

or

```
std::cout << CSnmpMaintenanceSwitchInstance;
```

Operator is declared as `friend` so it could access private and protected members of `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch`.

The first parameter is declared as non-constant reference since the output stream should be modified(some data will be written to it) by the default nature of `oeprator<<`.

The second parameter is declared as a constant reference because `operator<<` should not change it (by it's default nature).

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it is deaclared as `friend` is that you may want to directly reach and use some private variables in the overloaded operator.

Because you give the object `CSnmpMaintenanceSwitch`  as a `constant reference`, it is quaranteed that it will not modify the private data